# Edit options for shapes in Photoshop (cant seem to edit after creation)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When i first create a shape in Photoshop i get lots of options for fill / line colour, line weight etc. But if i click of that shape layer, on to another layer, then back to the shape layer, i cant seem to get the same options back. Any ideas where i can access the same options menu when editing a shape ?

[image: initial set of options]
[image: options when i try to edit]

Answer (score 0):

You need to be with the shape tool selected to get the shape options.

Comment: Thanks @naty - Couldn't get this to work, but instead using the path selection tool brought up the options